# Two titile bars on a single screen in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am trying to build a screen in BlackBerry. In which there should be a second title bar just below the original title bar. Also the second title bar should be fixed and it should not be scrolled with vertical scroll.

Need some advice on this issue.

Comment: Make a HorizontalFieldManager with flag no_verticalscroll and no Horizontal scroll. And add the contents to it .... and add this hfm just below the title bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the second title and the original title bar on a [VerticalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html). Then just set that `VerticalFieldManager` as title, as it's possible to set any `Field`, `Manager` instance as title.

Check [public void setTitle(Field title)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html#setTitle%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29) and following example.

```java
public class DemoScreen extends MainScreen {
    public DemoScreen() {
        super();

        // Prepare a Custom Title
        long style = NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | USE_ALL_WIDTH;
        VerticalFieldManager myTitle = new VerticalFieldManager(style);

        // Set background color.
        myTitle.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GRAY));

        // Add any numbers/types of field
        myTitle.add(new LabelField("First line."));
        myTitle.add(new LabelField("The second line."));

        // Set the Title
        setTitle(myTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: setBanner() is also useful here