# Issue in title and label field bar

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have a title bar and just below that i have a label field,i am facing a issue like as and when i scroll down the lable field "timezoneTitle " is not visible.Its visible only when i scroll up.I want to keep it fixed even if the user scrolss up and down,how to handle this?

```
LabelField title= new LabelField("welcome", LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);

hfm.add(title);



 // title for timezone
  LabelField timezoneTitle = new LabelField("", LabelField.ELLIPSIS
            | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER) {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
setTitle(vm);
add(timezoneTitle );
```

Comment: use settitle to timezoneTitle

Comment: we cannot have setTittle twice i am already having a single title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a main  vertical field VFM ......add hfm to VFM(vfm.add(hfm)) & add time zone field to VFM(vfm.add(tzmger)).

Comment: did you mean that this solved the issue ? if it solved please push it up and mark it as solution,

Comment: The question was asked by `sheetal_roswal`, and @harqs is verifying the answers. The same question (almost), http://stackoverflow.com/q/10928625/431639 was asked by another user. And none of these question marked solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your main screen into two vertical field managers(vfm1 &vfm2) and add these two fields to maine screen(VFM),1st add time zone to vfm1 and add label field to vfm2.(for vfm1 set the flag NO_VERTICALSCROLL).

Comment: you should add these two fields to main screen

Comment: i have tried and code is edited as above ,its not getting fixed,i have a list after the tzMgr on which i scroll then the tzMgr is not visisble

Comment: did you mean that this solved the issue ? if it solved please push it up and mark it as solution,(tick mark)

Comment: ya marked up,i am posting one more query on alignment please see if you can solve this also ,"how to align the images at the bottom"